# Split the selection area of two columns (tabular, or minipage, or whatever works)

Tags: tables, two-column, minipage

I use a tabular environment to do this 2x2 table:

[image]

These are input and output samples of a program.

In a PDF viewer, I wanna be able to select only one of the sides of this table, but my viewer only allows me to select like this:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to select only one of the sides? Maybe something with the minipage environment?

My TeX code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{ttfamily}
\begin{tabular}{L{6cm}|L{6cm}}
    \normalfont \textbf{Entrada} & \normalfont \textbf{Saída}     \\ \hline
    3 3 1     & 15     \\
    1 2 10    & 15     \\
    1 3 5     &        \\
    2 3 3     &        \\
    3 3 2     &        \\
    1 2 10    &        \\
    1 3 5     &        \\
    2 3 3     &        \\
\end{tabular}
\end{ttfamily}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you're using a system for which the Okular PDF viewer is available, using that is an option. It has a selection tool where arbitrary rectangles can be selected and copied.

Comment: But I need a portable solution... This always depends on the viewer?

Comment: I mean... I've seen some PDF documents with two columns that my viewer is able to select only one of the sides. That makes me think that all I need to do is use the correct environment/option in my TeX source. Could I be right?

Comment: I don't know, so I won't speculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct the `tabular` in a column-wise fashion, rather than the default row-wise fashion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily
% Construct tabular by-row (default approach)
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}|p{6cm}}
  \normalfont \textbf{Entrada} & \normalfont \textbf{Saída} \\
  \hline
  3 3 1     & 15     \\
  1 2 10    & 15     \\
  1 3 5     &        \\
  2 3 3     &        \\
  3 3 2     &        \\
  1 2 10    &        \\
  1 3 5     &        \\
  2 3 3     &
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% Construct tabular by-column
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
  \normalfont \textbf{Entrada} & \normalfont \textbf{Saída} \\
  \hline
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{6cm}@{}}
    3 3 1  \\ 1 2 10 \\ 1 3 5 \\ 2 3 3 \\ 3 3 2 \\
    1 2 10 \\ 1 3 5  \\ 2 3 3
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{6cm}@{}}
    15 \\ 15
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The first `tabular` select this way (by row):

[image]

The second `tabular` select this way (by column):

[image]

Comment: By the way, I'm sure I've answered this exact question before. I'm just unable to find it.